# I find reading Java written by others very difficult

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit

I have been working with Java for the last 3 years. I think I'm okay at developing and writing code. But recently I took a new job and have found two major problems:

1. Reading an trying to understand other peoples code, it's a different domain, and this could be the reason why I'm struggling. but I'm really struggling to understand the code.
2. Writing production quality code, I keep being told to improve my code. I never had any problems with it prior.

Any helpful hints and tips as to what I can do please.

p.s. I read and practice all the time, the standard books: Effective Java, Beginning Java, ooad, Design Patterns... etc.

Comment: I don't understand the `junit` tag...

Comment: For 2) ask for where exactly it us wrong and what should be better in effect ask for a code review

Comment: There **isn't a question** here, you're just making some statements. I doubt many people here care that you find it difficult to read other people's code, and there's really nothing we can do to help you with it anyway. Reading, and understanding, code written by others is a skill that you'll have to develop.

Comment: This should be reopened.  Coding style is a programming problem.

Comment: Style guidelines like http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html , http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html and http://developers.sun.com/sunstudio/products/archive/whitepapers/java-style.pdf should give you a better idea of how to write code in a style that others don't consider foreign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) Reading an trying to understand other peoples code, its a different domain, and this could be the reason why im struggling.. but im really struggling to understand the the code.

Its never easy, even after 20 years of development.  The best you can do is to learn to make your code as simple to understand as possible. ;)

> 2) Writing production quality code, I keep being told to improve my code.. never had any problems with it prior.

That can mean any number of things.  I suggest you try to learn their practices. e.g. do they mean they expect more unit tests, code reviews, different structures of code.  It could be that they are having trouble reading your code. ;)

Comment: Its easy to read/understand code which follows the practices you are used to.

Comment: Stepping through with a debugger e.g. in Eclipse can help alot in understanding other peoples code, maybe that's an option for you.

Comment: Stepping through your code in a debugger would answer 10% of the questions on this forum. ;)

Comment: The biggest problem I have reading other peoples code is resisting the urge to change it. :D